# Connection Refused on Port 9000 for Logstash Deployment on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, jenkins-plugins

I'm attempting to use the [Statistics Gathering](https://plugins.jenkins.io/statistics-gatherer/%3E) Jenkins plugin to forward metrics to Logstash. The plugin is configured with the following url: `http://logstash.monitoring-observability:9000`. Both Jenkins and Logstash are deployed on Kubernetes. When I run a build, which triggers metrics forwarding via this plugin, I see the following error in the logs:

```
2022-02-19 23:29:20.464+0000 [id=263]   WARNING o.j.p.s.g.util.RestClientUtil$1#failed: The request for url http://logstash.monitoring-observability:9000/ has failed.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:173
```

I get the same behavior when I exec into the jenkins pod and attempt to curl logstash:

```
jenkins@jenkins-7889fb54b8-d9rvr:/$ curl -vvv logstash.monitoring-observability:9000
*   Trying 10.52.9.143:9000...
* connect to 10.52.9.143 port 9000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to logstash.monitoring-observability port 9000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to logstash.monitoring-observability port 9000: Connection refused
```

I also get the following error in the logstash logs:

```
[ERROR] 2022-02-20 00:05:43.450 [[main]<tcp] pipeline - A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Tcp port=>9000, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_f96babad-299c-42ab-98e0-b78c025d9476", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, host=>"jenkins-server.devops-tools", ssl_verify=>false, id=>"0fddd9afb2fcf12beb75af799a2d771b99af6ac4807f5a67f4ec5e13f008803f", enable_metric=>true, mode=>"server", proxy_protocol=>false, ssl_enable=>false, ssl_key_passphrase=><password>>
  Error: Cannot assign requested address
  Exception: Java::JavaNet::BindException
  Stack: sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

Here is my jenkins-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: devops-tools
  labels:
    app: jenkins-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-server
    spec:
      securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1000 
            runAsUser: 1000
      serviceAccountName: jenkins-admin
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          env:
          - name: LOGSTASH_HOST
            value: logstash
          - name: LOGSTASH_PORT
            value: "5044"
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: elasticsearch-logging
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
            value: elastic
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
            value: changeme
          image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            requests:
              memory: "500Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - name: httpport
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlpport
              containerPort: 50000
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/login"
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/login"
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 3
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-data
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home         
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: jenkins-pv-claim
```

Here is my jenkins-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-server
  namespace: devops-tools
  annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
      prometheus.io/path:   /
      prometheus.io/port:   '8080'
spec:
  selector: 
    app: jenkins-server
    k8s-app: jenkins-server
  type: NodePort  
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30000
```

Here is my logstash-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: monitoring-observability
  labels:
    app: logstash
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        env:
          - name: JENKINS_HOST
            value: jenkins-server
          - name: JENKINS_PORT
            value: "8080"
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf
```

Here is my logstash-service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: monitoring-observability
  labels:
    app: logstash
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "logstash"
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  type: ClusterIP
```

Here is my logstash configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: monitoring-observability
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      tcp {
        port => "9000"
        codec => "json"
        host => "jenkins-server.devops-tools"
        ssl_verify => "false"
      }
    }
    filter {
      if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
      }
      if [ClientHost] {
        geoip {
          source => "ClientHost"
        }
      }
    }
    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "elasticsearch-logging:9200" ]
        }
    }
```

There are no firewalls configured in my cluster that would be blocking traffic on port 9000. I have also tried this same configuration with port `5044` and get the same results. It seems as though my logstash instance is not actually listening on the `containerPort`. Why might this be?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by updating the configmap to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: monitoring-observability
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      tcp {
        port => "9000"
        codec => "json"
        ssl_verify => "false"
      }
    }
    filter {
      if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
      }
      if [ClientHost] {
        geoip {
          source => "ClientHost"
        }
      }
    }
    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "elasticsearch-logging:9200" ]
        }
    }
```

Note that all references to the jenkins host have been removed.